# Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.2.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: android, exception, gradle

After I downloaded the new Android Studio version on 04/01/2024 and sync the gradle file, ?I've got this error log during build:

```
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.2.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:    
    
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.2.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.2.1' apply false
}
```

I can't find any help on troubleshoot and compile the application.

Answer (score 3):

For me this happened when I imported a new module into the project. which led to the creation of the **settings.gradle** file. After removing the **settings.gradle** and adding `include(":mylib")` to the **settings.gradle.kts**, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a strange situation:

- AndroidStudio & some dependency-management plugins **suggest AGP (Android Gradle Plugin) to be updated to `8.2.1` version**
- But nither official changelog (https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#versioning-update) nor MavenCentral (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin) **do not contain `8.2.1` version**, only `8.2.0`

So, the current (2024-01-05) **solution is to downgrade AGP to `8.2.0`** until next release will be officially available

Answer (score 0):

my error is fixed by proxy

some countries are boycott, use VPN or proxy. for example set `freedomofdevelopers`

**file->settings->Appearance & Behavior->system setting->HTTP proxy**

choose `Manual proxy configuaration` then choose `HTTP`
hostname = fodev.org
port 8118